# *ngIf check is array empty then show message

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I used the following code to check if array is empty then show message else show the list. But it only shows list is working. ***"No messages"*** is not displaying. What's wrong here?

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of globalArray">
    <div *ngIf="!globalArray?.length > 0">
        <p>No messages</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="globalArray?.length > 0">
        <ion-item>
            {{item.message}}
        </ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Try this condition `*ngIf = ' globalArray?.length == 0` and see

Answer (score 26, accepted):

because in your array

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of globalArray">
    <div *ngIf="!globalArray?.length > 0">
        <p>No messages</p>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="globalArray?.length > 0">
        <ion-item>
            {{item.message}}
        </ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-row>
```

you are directly iterating and checking the length of an array inside ngFor, which will never execute. you need to check the length outside ngFor or before iterating the array. you can check this from ts file too, or you can handle this in your view.

In your view you can handle like:

```
<div *ngIf="!globalArray || globalArray.length === 0">
        <p>No messages</p>
    </div>
<div *ngIf="globalArray || globalArray.length > 0">
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of globalArray">
        <ion-item>
            {{item.message}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
</div>
```

In the .ts file you can similarly check the array length and make a variable toggle on basis of this and use ngIf with that variable on both the Div.

Answer (score 7):

You are doing it the wrong way.

Here are some suggested solutions:

1. Try the new `ngIfElse` syntax:

   ```html
   <div *ngIf="globalArray && globalArray.length >0 then showData else hideData">
   <ng-template #showData>Show Data</ng-template>
   <ng-template #hideData>Hide Data</ng-template>
   ```

   with this, you can conditionally show the `ng-template`.
2. the other way.

   ```html
   <div *ngIf="globalArray && globalArray.length >0">Show Data</div>

   <div *ngIf="globalArray == undefined || globalArray.length == 0">Hide Data</div>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if globalArray is empty while you are inside the loop. It does not execute inside the loop if it is empty. Place the checking outside like this:

```
    <div *ngIf="!globalArray || globalArray.length === 0">
        <p>No messages</p>
    </div>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of globalArray">
        <ion-item>
            {{item.message}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
```

The checking for when globalArray is not empty inside the loop is not needed. It will not iterate if there are no rows to iterate.